# Not able to add Domain in salesforce with Type A DNS record

Tags: community, force.com-sites, force.com, site.com, custom-domain

We are facing a redirection issue with registered salesforce domains. We have registered “www.xyz.org.uk” domain in Salesforce. While hitting the https://www.xyz.org.uk URL in the browser it redirects to the correct site but error with main http://xyz.org.uk URL. Here we are not using ‘www.’ And try with the main domain and it's not working as expected.

So to tackle this issue we are trying to add the main domain to the Salesforce domains list but we are getting the below error message from Salesforce:

“*Error: Salesforce.com can't validate the domain. The CNAME record may still be processing (which can take up to 24 hours), or the domain may not belong to you. Make sure the domain name xyz.org.uk uses xyz.org.uk.00d0y000000yczyua0.live.siteforce.com as its CNAME target and try again later.*”

In the Org domain records for 'www.xyz.org.uk' which is linked with CNAME Type DNS record mapping,
Now we want to create one more domain record for 'xyz.org.uk' and for that in the DNS server, we have a Type A record.

Could you please help us to resolve this issue?